# Allow user to upload images and add title/short description

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a DIV on my page that represents a section called Promotions.

1. Within this DIV, I want to create three rounded boxes by where the user can upload/change the images when they want, to display the top 3 promotional items. How can I approach this?
2. Alongside/below these images, I want the user to also be able to place a title/short description - how to do this?
3. To also have a "VIEW ALL" option so that the user can view all images on another web page.

Would also like it to possibly be in a horizontal carousel using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) create the 3 divs, and set them a border (with css). in each div put a iframe that call a php script with the form, with the file input to upload the image and add the title/description. optional, after the user uploaded the image you can call a js function on the container page (something like parent.myFunction()) to make any desired action (like show the link to see the images as carousel.

the idea to put a iframe and load the image there, is just so you can have a upload of image whiteout needing to reload the page, you can do the same just putting the forms in the divs whiteout the iframe, but the page will reload in each upload.

for 3) i can't help you, i usually use mootools for js, but anyways there is plenty of jquery scripts for that on the web :)